# Python numerically solved harmonic oscillator graph generates unwanted results

Tags: python, physics, numerical

Ive been trying to numerically solve for the graph of a basic harmonic oscillator but a problem occurs when acceleration on the object is proportional to the inverse of the distance from the centre:

```
import math
from pylab import *
xg = [2]
xt = [0]
k = 1

dt = 1/1000
Vx = 0
for i in range(800000):
    a = -1/xg[i-1] #acceleration on the object
    Vx = Vx + dt*a
    xg.append(xg[i-1]+Vx*dt)
    xt.append(i*dt)
plot(xt,xg)
show()
```

As you can see it seems to dip down and not return for some reason.

[image]

I am wondering what is causing this to happen, I've been trying to solve this for hours.

*Yes, I am new to python, stack exchange and solving problems numerically. Any feedback is appreciated*

Comment: Your code doesn't work on my computer. It just print a point on the screen as my expect. I'm wondering how could you produce such a graph?

Comment: Note that `dt = 1/1000` will always be `0` in Python. `dt= 1.0/1000` may be what you want.

Comment: I guess he is using python3. Concerning your problem: The acceleration of a harmonic oscillator is proportional to the distance. Therefore, you have to compute the acceleration as: `a = -xg[i-1]`. Furthermore, you will get a drift with this kind of first order integration.

Comment: Just notice it's Python3, then `dt = 1/1000` works well.

Comment: If you want more accuracy, you could also look into the [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) method, which is (similar to) a polynomial expansion of Euler's method (which is basically what you have here)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
import math
from pylab import *
xt = [2]
t = [0]
k = 1

dt = 0.0001
Vx = 0
for i in range(800000):
    t.append(dt*i)
    a = -k*xt[i]
    xt.append(xt[i] + dt*Vx)
    Vx = Vx + dt*a
plot(t,xt)
show()
```

You end up with this: (I also decreased the time step fyi to 1/10000)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an acceleration proportional to the inverse of the distance, the numerical values will diverge when xg is near 0, inducing numerical instability.